# How to make a Tree Navigator control in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I know the **TreeView** control of UWP. What I'm looking for is a tree navigator control like the [Syncfusion Tree Navigator](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sftreenavigator/overview) control. It gives a unique layout to arrange items in hierarchical tree structure without occupying much space. It displays the expanded item in a navigator.

Maybe, you will ask me why not use `Syncfusion Tree Navigator` control directly. It's because it's not open source. I'm more interested in how to make such a control. I do not know where to start. Maybe, I need to do a lot of customizations. UWP experts, if you know how to make such a control. Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) class and have each navigation element expend to reveal nested elements when possible.

Edit : There's [this guide](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2018/06/08/using-a-treeview-control-for-navigation-in-uwp/) to implement everything in the navigation pane by yourself. Else, you could wait for the `NavigationView` class to [support this feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/projects/9).

Comment: How to expend the nested elements like the `Syncfusion Tree Navigator`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it exactly like them, but you can create your own `DataTemplate` to apply to the `NavigationViewItem.ContentTemplate` field, basically overriding it with what you want. You could make it so it's a `ListView`, for example. Anyways, the particular feature  you ask for is [in progress](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/79). So you might want to wait for that to be done for an easier solution ([it seems pretty advanced](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/commit/548276e2660f87d47196cfbd659f0a0f1f792224), so you can base your solution on this).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it still was not very helpful to me.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you only wanted pointers to know where to start. Anyways, if you've seen the links I've sent you, you can see that one current solution is to use the TreeView inside a custom navigation pane. Fear not, [this guide](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2018/06/08/using-a-treeview-control-for-navigation-in-uwp/) can help you do this.